# Rearrange in each row the largest element by absolute value with a diagonal

Tags: python, nested, sequence

form and output the sequence a[4,4] obtained from the sequence b by permutation in each row of the largest element in absolute magnitude with a diagonal

I did everything, but I don't understand how to rearrange the largest element with a diagonal in each row by absolute value...

```
from random import*
from math import*
n = 4
m = 4
B = []
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    for j in range(m):
        b += [-3 + 6 * randint(0,1)]
    B.append(b)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(B[i][j],'\t', end=' ')
    print()

print()
A = [] 
for i in range(n): 
    A.append([]) 
    for j in range(m): 
        A[i].append(B[i][j])

max_element = max(abs((A[i] for i in range(len(A)))))
for i in range(len(A)):
    if i == max_element:
        A[i] = 
  
print(*A)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Can you please give an example for a sequence of permutations that rearrange the rows? Add a sample input 4x4 matrix. Show all the stages that rearrange the rows. the statement "rearrange the largest element with a diagonal" is unclear, so an example may help.